# What are actor list in house of the future in UML?

Tags: uml, actor

I want to know what are the actor list in a house of the future?
who will be primary actors, supporting actors and offstage actors?
house of the future includes-
intelligent refrigerators
remote access
configurable living
smart environments.

Any answers would be really appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering such a home of the future you could think of actors like:

- User using the appliances from home
- User using the appliances remotely
- e.g. fire squad brigade - get connected to smart smoke detection etc.
- e.g. online grocery retailer sytem - gets access to fridge's api and can automatically send a courier to the home
- e.g. water provider system - gets access to detailed data about water usage, can suggest changes to the plan e.g. based on time of the day etc.
- and on and on...

Remember on UML diagram if more users playthe same role you just indicate this as one actor

Comment: Thank you.
Now I got it.

Comment: Well, actors are not just persons but also systems.

Comment: Well, I think this is quite obvious that I don't refer here to grocery retailer as a person behind the cashier, but the system behind it.

Comment: Not really. _Actors are all users of the system._ is not correct. Just use the phrase from my answer and you're done.

Comment: I deleted this sentence Thomas to get this inconsistency out of the way. Thanks.

Comment: can sensors and cameras also comes under actors list?

Comment: No, these are parts of the system under consideration, not actors

Comment: Thank a lot.
here is my actor list:-
1. Home Owner
2. Family Members
3. Relatives
4. Friends
5. Security System
6. Online Grocery System
7. Water Provider System
8. Mobile application system
9. Mail Delivery Person
10. Voice Command System
11. Remote Control System
12. Refrigerators System
13. Fire Brigade system
14. Cops.
Is this list correct?

Comment: Well, it depends on the functionality of the home. e.g. if relatives and friends are both visitors of the home, than perhaps it makes sense to group it as "Visitor", unless from the perspective of the system in scope they play a specifically different role. In UML you also refer to an actor with singular name not plural, so "friend" instead of "friends". With some of the things you put there like "Refrigerator System" or "Remote Control" they look to me like the parts of home, not actors. In UML actors are closely linked to use cases. So think in perspective of different uses of such home.

Answer (score 1):

An actor is any person or system that interacts with the system under consideration. Yesterday. Today. Tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
so what will be the actors in Automated house?